# Error while adding a new filter to Weka

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying to add a new filter to Weka following the steps from this GIT repository:
https://github.com/alvarag/LSH-IS/

But at the final step using:

```
java -cp "absolute_path\filter.jar:weka.jar" weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

The command line gives me the following error:

> Could not find or load main class weka.gui.GUIChooser

Can someone please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I can execute it normally with this command in the jar location.

```
java -cp weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but that command you shared only opens Weka GUI. But what I want to do is run this one: java -cp instanceselection.jar:weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser

It supposed to add a new filter to Weka library